# Node.js - Why read property 'length' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets

Here is my code.
I am writing a program that links to GOOGLE spreadsheet. This is its problem reading function.

```
function getQuestions() {
  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
     auth: oauth2Client,
     spreadsheetId: mySheetId,
     range:encodeURI('123'),
  }, function(err, response) {
     if (err) {
        console.log('The API for reading the problem file caused a problem:' + err);
        return;
     }
     const rows = response.values;

     if (rows.length == 0) {
        console.log('No data found.');
     } else {
       myQuestions=rows;
       totalSteps=myQuestions[0].length;
       console.log('The questions to ask have been downloaded!');
     }
  });
}
```

but when I execute it, it will has an exception occurred.

```
(node:7380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bottest(Node.js)\index.js:53:15
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bottest(Node.js)\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src\apirequest.js:48:53
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

### Why is this?

Excuse me, could it be that the google spreadsheet passed in is not array at all?
Google seems to have an update to its spreadsheet, and the data types have been changed.But I don’t know what type of data is passed in the current table...

Comment: `rows` or `myQuestions[0]` is `undefined`. You have to debug to find out the reason.

Comment: As a simple way to debug I suggest you to use `console.log(myQuestions)` before `totalSteps=myQuestions[0].length;`. It's likely not an array, but rather an object with an array in it, or perhaps a JSON string which must be parsed (`JSON.parse(myQuestions)`).

Comment: Try it: `if(!rows?.length || !rows[0]?.length){ // no data found`

Answer (score -1):

`myQuestions[0]` is not an `array`. As a result, you are getting an error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Debug to find out the problem by using `console.log()`. Happy coding :)

Comment: How did you determine `rows` is an array?

Comment: `rows.length == 0` this line indicates that rows is an array. Also you can assume by the name of that variable.

Comment: `myQuestions[0].length` also similarly indicates `myQuestions[0]` is an array. my point was that without seeing the data, there is no way to know what those hold. You seemed to have some insight into what the data is but apparently, it was just a guess.